# Preserve /etc/network/interfaces configuration when changing PCIe cards

Tags: 16.04, networking, pci, pcie

I have several NICs in my Ubuntu 16.04 box (3 of them at the moment). As best I can tell their names are related to their PCIe names. My problem is that when I add or remove a card of any type (graphics, HBA, etc) the interface names seem to change and then the booting hangs for several minutes trying to bring the network up. If I have to reboot several times then this really adds up.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet manual

auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual

auto enp6s0f0
iface enp6s0f0 inet manual

auto enp6s0f1
iface enp6s0f1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    hwaddress 50:e5:49:ed:72:3d
    bridge_ports enp8s0 enp6s0f0 enp6s0f1 enp5s0
    bridge_stp off
```

Comment: did you look into persistent-net-rules for udev  ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl  I haven't (never heard of those things), but I will.

Answer (score 2):

**Udev has a mechanism to fixate the name of network devices**

---

First, take note of your interfaces mac-addresses. You can see them with `ip a` or `ifconfig -a`

Second, the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`  has to be created manually in 16.04.

Use your favorite editor

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

The line for fixing the interface name of the NIC with MAC address "02:01:02:03:04:05" to "eth0" is:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="02:01:02:03:04:05", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
```

So for your first interface called `enp8s0`it would be

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<the-mac-address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="enp8s0"
```

You have to make an entry for each network card. This takes effect on reboot.

---

- Disclaimer: For Ubuntu versions before 16.04 you have to add `KERNEL=="eth*"` *